# Serial downvoting of my old question

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting

I am banned from asking questions on the main site due to the previous four questions. I wrote them when I just joined the site almost one year ago, but in recent days I am getting downvoted on my questions every day.

I get at least two downvotes on my questions, and the downvoter doesn't give any reason for downvoting, and I am seriously pissed off by this, because the serial downvoter regularly downvotes my posts, irrespective of my content.

Taking the example of this question,

*[Why is gravity so special?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524370/why-is-gravity-so-special)*

This is the most recent question I asked, and I received a downvote on it. And the serial downvoting is very irritating and discouraging!

Edit:) today too I got one one down vote on my old question.

[Reason for change in colour of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486541/reason-for-change-in-colour-of-light) same as yesterday one. 
And 
[Why is gravity so special?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524370/why-is-gravity-so-special) it really scare me now.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7491/249968

Comment: Useful: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Serial+down+voting+

Comment: Note: Your (automated) ban is the result of much more questions than four - those are only the visible, i.e. non-deleted, ones

Comment: What is your evidence that the same person is downvoting multiple questions of yours? I think this is a baseless accusation.

Comment: About your edit - that is likely a consequence of the "meta effect"; where posting about something on meta brings more attention to that post, for better or worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are automated tools to reverse serial voting, but they are not perfect. If the downvotes persist for more than a day, raise a moderator flag if you think there is uncaught serial voting going on.

Please remember that "serial voting" refers to a single other user targeting you with their downvoted specifically. Ordinary users do not have access to any information to determine that this is, in fact, what is going on - it is easy to see patterns where there are none.

Comment: Sir what to do I do because everyday I can see my post getting down voted. With no comment.@ACuriousMind.

Comment: @Yuvraj as he said you should raise a custom moderator flag if the case persists.

Comment: There is *no obligation* for a downvoter to comment on the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @G. Smith I agree - did I write anything that gave you a different impression?

Comment: @ACuriousMind No! I was responding to Yuvraj’s comment complaining about downvotes without comments, and I forgot to add the appropriate @. I know you know the rules of the site, but perhaps Yuvraj doesn’t.

Comment: @G.Smith that is very bad, that downvoter is not obliged to write an comment, why so? Then how can the question quality be improve we all here to make this site a better place and learning should be in habit. That is totally wrong.

Comment: @G.smith that is total irony because on main site every user ask for comment whenever people think that question quality is not upto the mark.

Comment: @yuvrai That has been discussed many times before, e. g. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12433/50583, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817/50583

Comment: @YuvrajSingh... They are entitled to ask, but not to get what they ask for. Allowing (but not encouraging) downvoting without commenting is part of the intentional design of StackExchange.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your 4 questions now and here is what I have found so far:

- [Why is gravity so special?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524370/249968)

3 upvotes and 2 downvotes

- [Reason for change in colour of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/486541/249968)

1 upvote and 2 downvotes

- [What is the reason for Moon and satellite in free fall condition? [duplicate]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485603/249968)

3 upvotes and 2 downvotes

- [How can we prove that light is an Electromagnetic wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485084/249968)

2 upvotes and 2 downvotes

Now either of the following can be considered:

- You are getting serially downvoted by 2 users (with reputation $\gt 125$)
- You are/were being downvoted by more than two users, who might have downvoted as per the quality of your question.

I can't conclude which of these two might be the case but from my experience on the site (I am quite new user, just a month old) I can say that the second case is most probable. But who knows what might be the case. So as @ACuriousMind says you should raise a custom moderator flag and then see what happens.